# How to Redirect Intent Link to An App

Tags: android, html, deep-linking

I just created a HTML file that has deep link to open an Android app.
I run the HTML using mobile Chrome.
The link below works

```
<a href="intent://rtanah.com/app#Intent;scheme=rtanah;package=twebble.com.rtanah;end">
  android-app://twebble.com.rtanah/rtanah/rtanah.com/app
</a>
```

But I can't make it redirect by using a meta tag or JavaScript.
I don't want the user to click the link everytime they open the webpage.

Can anyone show me how to?

Comment: Please provide some information whether you are browsing with webview inside the app or what is the situation?

Comment: "I can't make it redirect using meta or javascript" -- if you are saying that one or more Web browsers do not support launching your app based upon a `<meta>` tag or a JavaScript call, please contact the browser authors.

Comment: I am using Mobile Chrome. Yes this meta won't work
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=intent://rtanah.com/app#Intent;scheme=rtanah;package=twebble.com.rtanah;end" />